# how to deploy php site using xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, deployment, xampp

I have a pre developed PHP project and I need to deploy it using xampp

What should I do about the data base problem that popup to me :

> Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL

Comment: The error message seems to be clear: Make sure you can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is message may be appear depend in many situations:
1) You didn't setup correctly connection to database in your application.
2) The database server hasn't been start yet.
So, I think the first reason is your situation, since httpd start correctly and rarely MySQL server have trouble to start.

Comment: thnx every one ,, it was about the privileged for the user